# postgreSQL Duplicate rows counting on join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one complicated question. I'll try to explain it with example:

have one table that have primary key, and I want to join other table there the first's table primary key is foreign key, and I want If in the second table there is duplicate foreign key to select the number of repeatability. For example:

1-st table:

```
  id    name 
  ---  -----
  1     Greg
  2     Alan 
  3    George 
  4     John 
  5     Peter
```

2-nd table

```
 id       aid        data   
 ---     -----      -------
 1        2          CCCV   
 2        2          VVVV 
 3        3          DDDDD 
 4        3          SSSS 
 5        4          PPPPP
```

I want the result of the join to be:

```
 id(1st table)  aid   name    Data   Number
 -----------    ----  -----   -----  -----
 1               null  Greg    null   1
 2                1    Alan    CCCV   1
 2                2    Alan    VVVV   2
 3                3    George  DDDDD  1
 3                4    George  SSSS   2
 4                5    John    PPPPP  1
 5               null  Peter   null   1
```

I searched a lot, I couldn't find anything. Maybe I do not know how search, or there is no such thing as what I want to do.

Comment: MySQL and PostGreSQL have very different capabilities. I'd use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create your final column, which exists in PostGreSQL, but it does not exist in MySQL.  Which aare you actually using?

Comment: Data as SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/319f6

Comment: I'm Using PostgreSQL, but it gives me error in "OVER" statement

Comment: @dna - What *exact* version of PostGreSQL? And what *exact* error message?  *(Note that it works in SQL Fiddle...)*

Comment: @Dems the version ti 8.3, I red that this version not supports the ROW_NUMBER() function, that is why It gives me an error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table2.id as aid, Table1.name, Table2.data,
GREATEST(1, (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM Table2 t2
             WHERE t2.aid = Table1.id
             AND t2.id <= Table2.id))
AS number
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table2.aid = Table1.id
ORDER BY id, aid;
```

works in both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, you've tagged this both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

This answer is for PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT
  table1.id,
  table2.aid,
  table1.name,
  table2.data,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table1.id ORDER BY table2.aid) AS number
FROM
  table1
LEFT JOIN
  table2
    ON table1.id = table2.aid
```

Comment: Gah, beat me to it. Here's an SQLFiddle with the data and your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/319f6/1

Comment: It gives me an error: "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "OVER""

Comment: From the example in the question, it seems that the aid in the result table should be table2.id

Comment: I got it.....my PostgreSQL server version is 8.3, the support of the function is after 8.4. If Anyone can offer me an Alternative......I'll be very thankfull

Comment: @CraigRinger: Thanks for still posting the fiddle. Saved me some work. :)

Comment: @dna ... and that's why you should always mention your PostgreSQL version in questions.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Queries for PostgreSQL 8.3 which has no window functions.</sup>
With *bigger tables* it is regularly much faster to use a `JOIN` instead of a [correlated sub-query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).
The first query aggregates values for `Table2` *before* joining to `Table1`, which should befaster, too:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.aid, t1.name, t2.data, COALESCE(t2.ct, 1) AS number
FROM   Table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN  (
    SELECT x.aid, x.data, count(y.aid) + 1 AS ct
    FROM   Table2 x
    LEFT   JOIN Table2 y ON x.aid = y.aid AND x.id > y.id
    GROUP  BY x.aid, x.data
    ) t2 ON t2.aid = t1.id
ORDER  BY t1.id, t2.ct;
```

And `ORDER BY` should be fixed.

Alternative without sub-query. Might be faster, yet:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.aid, t1.name, t2.data, count(*) + count(t3.id) AS number
FROM   Table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.aid = t1.id
LEFT   JOIN Table2 t3 ON t3.aid = t2.aid AND t3.id < t2.id
GROUP  BY t1.id, t2.aid, t1.name, t2.data
ORDER  BY t1.id, count(t3.id);
```

Not sure, didn't test with a bigger set. Test performance with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Could you report back your results?

Comment: The thing is that this was only an example. The real job is more complicated, in the real query joins more than 15 tables, and when I add the logic that you suggested it brings me an error in one of the columns that is not affected by the changes. I'm not sure if I paste the whole query is anyone can understand what I'm talking about...

Comment: If you are interested I could paste the whole query with the adding that you suggested?

Comment: @dna: I'd say go ahead and open a new question that displays your complete (simplified) query. You will most probably get a fix shortly. Me first guess would be un-aggregated columns. But just ask a new question, that beats guesswork. You can always link to this question to provide more context. Use the link provided under "share".